# Raise DTS events in child class of Script Main (SSIS Script Task)

Tags: c#, sql-server, inheritance, ssis, dts

I have a situation where a child class of ScriptMain (the entry point class of my SSIS Script task) needs to fire a Dts event warning within a try catch statement.

The problem I am having is that I cannot access Dts from my child class. My guess is that this would be a grandchild attempting to access a method of a grandparent. As a solution, I inherited the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase` class within my child class. However, this still results in a `null` `Dts` instance.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase 
{
  public void Main()
  {
    ChildClass hi = new ChildClass();
    hi.Execute();
  }
}

 public class ChildClass : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase 
 {
  public void Execute()
  { 
    foreach(var request in createETRequests())
    {
      try{
        //do scary stuff
      }
      catch
      {
        //handle error
        this.TrackError("oh no!");
      }
   }
 }
 private IEnumerable<TriggeredSend> createETRequests()
 {
   TriggeredSend triggeredSendObject = new TriggeredSend();
   //do stuff within another foreach including the below return
      yield return triggeredSendObject;
 }

 private void TrackError(string foo)
 {
    //NULL EXCEPTION when called from child instance
    Dts.Events.FireWarning(2000, "hello there SSIS", foo, String.Empty, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the child class bubble something up to the parent (set a public variable/property or something) and then fire the warning from the main script.

Comment: Would this be the same as calling a method within the parent from the child class? Pretty much putting the TrackError in the parent? I tried that and I get the same problem. The problem I face with just setting a variable is that the try catch is within a for loop... I'll update my question.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger and seen the TrackError function get called?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple breakpoints set. In all cases, `Dts` is null. Unless the event is fired within `ScriptMain` by a request that originated within that class.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the DTS object as an argument to the child class and use that object to fire information. On the parent class, pass the DTS object and on the child class define a variable of type `ScriptObjectModel` and consume it on child class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).